# superposition of states, spin 1/2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Something was wrong...

> Two particles, their spin are 1/2.
>
> The hamiltonian is $H=\gamma s_1 \cdot s_2$
>
> At t=0, the state $|\alpha(0)>$ is such as  $s_{1z}|\alpha(0)>=\hbar/2  |\alpha(0)>$ and $s_{2z}|\alpha(0)>=\hbar/2 |\alpha(0)>$. Find the
>   state $|\alpha(0)>$.

I think that $|\alpha(0)>=|1,1>$ in the base of total angular momentum, i.e. |1/2, 1/2> in the other one. But the correct result seems to be $|\alpha(0)>=1/ \sqrt2 [|1,1; 1/2, 1/2> + 1/ \sqrt 2 (|1,0; 1/2, 1/2>+|0,0; 1/2, 1/2>)]$.. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the state is clearly $$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)_1\otimes\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)_2.$$

Or $\left|s_1 s_{z1} s_2 s_{z2}\right\rangle=\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2}\right\rangle.$

So really you are just trying to write it in the total angular momentum basis. This is what Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are for, and you can look them up on a table or you can derive them. Using the basis $\left|j j_z s_1 s_2 \right\rangle$ you get $\left|1 1 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle.$ As you mentioned.

If you reversed it then $\boxed{\sqrt 1}\left|1 1 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle=\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2}\right\rangle.$ And  $\boxed{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}\left|1 0 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\boxed{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}\left|0 0\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle=\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{-1}{2}\right\rangle.$ And so you get that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|1 1 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|1 0 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|0 0\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2}\right\rangle+\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{-1}{2}\right\rangle.$$

Which isn't even normalized, so is the "answer" a mistake?

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't understood why my result is wrong. I have derived clebsh-Gordan coefficient.. It seems to me that it is correct but, if I'm wrong in checking the result against the tables, please, tell me

Comment: I'm not used to use your notation. I'm asking that: the state that has $s_{1z}=\hbar /2$ **and** $s_{2z}=\hbar /2$ is, in the base of total angular momentum, given by |1, 1>. Isn't it?

Comment: well, I don't know how to obtain the correct result then! can you explain me?

Comment: http://imgur.com/pSdDYdr this is my confusion..

Comment: Really sorry, made a typo.. updated question :)

Comment: Edited. It still seems like a mistake somewhere in your answer or your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't undertand how you have obtained $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|1 0 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left|0 0\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}\right\rangle=\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{+1}{2} \frac{1}{2} \frac{-1}{2}\right\rangle.$

Comment: I don't understand if you have looked for ∣1/2, +1/2, 1/2, −1/2⟩ and why.. I can't follow your steps. thanks again!

Comment: how is possible that the states $|1,0, s_1, s_2>$ and $|0,0, s_1, s_2>$ have $s_1=s_2=1/2$?

Comment: @sunrise I put boxes around the things I got from your Clebsch-Gordan table (second row), which matched my table too. And I used $s_1$ and $s_2$ for the spin of the two particles. So it is always spin 1/2. Only $s_{z1}$ and $s_{z2}$ can be $\pm 1/2.$

Comment: but why you have looked for the state ∣1/2, +1/2, 1/2, −1/2⟩? in this state s2z=-1/2... but we want s2z=1/2.. :(

Comment: @sunrise That's why I said "If you reversed it." Starting with the "answer" we show that it doesn't equal what we want and it isn't even normalized. And I don't know why you had those parenthesis in your "answer" the thing you put in parenthesis for unknown reasons is | 1/2 +1/2 1/2 -1/2>. We should be in agreement (now that we understand each other's notation) that the double up state has to be purely 11. I just can't tell if you are typing correctly, understood the question correctly or why you trust a clearly wrong answer. We might agree on everything except whether to trust your answer.

Comment: I'm not used to think that a result reported in a book is wrong. I'm used to think "Oh, I have made a mistake!" :) thanks for your support!